# Using not compiled media on Android

Tags: android, web-services, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android application. I'm very new on Android development.

I see on other projects that textures are hold on res directory. They have to be compiled and deployed into device.

I'm wondering if I can download a picture as a texture from a web service and use it.

I don't know if every media that I need has to be compiled.

Thanks.

Comment: Images in the res folder aren't "compiled", they are just there for easy referencing throughout your app.  You should be able to download an image and use it similarly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new on Android and I read somewhere that all images are compiled to be accessible by R.java.

Comment: You would probably not be accessing your downloaded images via R.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could download the pictures from the web and use them. If you plan on having changeable content then you should probably do so as well.
Adding Images to Res will have them included in the APK and, Then copied to the device on installation (Unless you use zipalign which should sometimes allow you to use content from the apk)